# Conditions of $x_1v_1 +..+x_kv_k = w$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a yes/no question with 3 options:

Let:

$$
v_1,...,v_k,w \in R^n
$$

1. If there are infinity number of solutions for $x_1v_1 +..x_kv_k = w$, therefore $k>n$
2. If $\forall w \in R$ there is a solution for $x_1v_1 +..x_kv_k = w$ therefore $k=n$
3. If there is a solution for $x_1v_1 +..x_kv_k = w$ so $k \leq n$

I answered it intuitively, i want a more orgenaized solution.

$1$ - no, take 2 linear dependent vectors and $w = 0$ for $n \geq 2$

$2$ - take base + linear dependent vectors.

$3$ - Im not sure how to answer.

Can someone give me a more formal way, especially for $3$?

Thanks.

Comment: $(2)$ and $(3)$ are false since the solution for $x_1v_1+x_2v_2+..+x_kv_k=w$ exist when $k\gt n,\forall w\in \mathbb{R}^n$ because then $L\{v_1,v_2,..,v_k\}=\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @student $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (where $k > n$) do not necessarily span $\mathbb{R}^n$, but yes, you can always *find* such a list -- for example, by taking a basis and adding on additional vectors to it.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers for (1) and (2) are basically correct. For (1), you can also just choose any linearly dependent list $v_1, ..., v_k, w$ (and make sure $k \leq n - 1$). For (2), yes, you can take any basis, then add on other vectors. For (3), you can use the same answer as for (2).

Formally, we can do the following: given a basis $u_1, ..., u_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, consider for example $u_1, ..., u_n, 2u_1$ which is a linearly dependent list of $n+1$ vectors that spans $\mathbb{R}^n$. This produces a counterexample to both (2) and (3).